# Need help with the error : : Apex CPU time limit exceeded

Tags: apex, trigger, governorlimits, cpulimit

I am receiving error in the below lines of code when I pass more than 200 records in the list. For the fewer records it is working fine. Is there any way to optimize the code to avoid the error.

There is no particular line numbers in which the code is getting stuck but mostly it is in the FOR loops. But it it always these 2 methods which I am providing in the code below. I am invoking the below class via a trigger upon after insert/update.

```
Public Class APTS_ProposalLineItemTriggerHandler 
{
    //Purpose of this method is to update some field values in the first 'Proposal' when a 'Proposal Line Item' is moved from one 'Proposal' to another. 'Proposal Line Item' is child of 'Proposal' object.
    Public Static Boolean IsUpdate = TRUE;
    Public Static Void UpdateOldNegoGroup(List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c> ProposalLineItems)
    {
        Set<ID> ProductId = New Set<ID>();
        Set<ID> PriceListId = New Set<ID>();
        Map<Id,Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c> PLIToUpdate = New Map<Id,Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c>();

        List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c> ProposalLineItem = [Select Id, Publishing_Status__c, Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c, Apttus_Proposal__Product__c, Apttus_QPConfig__PriceListId__c, Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__r.Price_Agreement_Name__c, Apttus_QPConfig__StartDate__c, Apttus_QPConfig__EndDate__c FROM Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c WHERE ID =: ProposalLineItems];

        FOR(Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c PLI : ProposalLineItems)
        {
            ProductId.Add(PLI.Apttus_Proposal__Product__c);
            PriceListId.Add(PLI.Apttus_QPConfig__PriceListId__c);
        }
        System.debug('---ProductId---'+ProductId+' '+ProductId.size());
        System.debug('---PriceListId---'+PriceListId+' '+PriceListId.size()); 

        List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c> APLIList = [Select  Id, Moved__c , APTS_Expired__c, APTS_Alert_Type__c,
            APTS_Action_Notes__c, APTS_Include__c, Negotiation_Status__c, Publishing_Status__c, XAE_Action_3__c, Apttus_Proposal__Product__c,
            Apttus_QPConfig__PriceListId__c, Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c, Moved_Date__c, Apttus_QPConfig__StartDate__c, Apttus_QPConfig__EndDate__c FROM Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c 
            WHERE Apttus_Proposal__Product__c =: ProductId AND Apttus_QPConfig__PriceListId__c =: PriceListId AND ID NOT IN :ProposalLineItems];

        System.debug('---APLIListSize---'+APLIList.Size());
        System.debug('---APLIListSize---'+APLIList);

            FOR(Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c PLI1 : APLIList)
            {
                FOR(Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c PLI2 : ProposalLineItem)
                {
                    IF((PLI1.Apttus_Proposal__Product__c == PLI2.Apttus_Proposal__Product__c) && (PLI1.Apttus_QPConfig__PriceListId__c == PLI2.Apttus_QPConfig__PriceListId__c) && (PLI1.Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c != PLI2.Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c))
                    {
                        Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c APLIU = New Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c();

                        APLIU.Id = PLI1.Id;
                        APLIU.Moved__c = TRUE; 
                        APLIU.Moved_Date__c = Date.today();              
                        APLIU.APTS_Alert_Type__c = 'Action';
                        APLIU.APTS_Action_Notes__c = 'This Part has been moved under "' + PLI2.Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__r.Price_Agreement_Name__c + '"';
                        //APLIU.APTS_Include__c = FALSE;
                        APLIU.XAE_Action_3__c = '';

                        //This code is to keep include checked in old part if it is moved to another part of non-overlapping dates negotiation groups. Added this on 24th Jan 2017
                        IF(PLI1.Apttus_QPConfig__EndDate__c > PLI2.Apttus_QPConfig__StartDate__c)
                        {
                            APLIU.APTS_Include__c = FALSE;
                        }
                        Else
                        {
                            APLIU.APTS_Include__c = TRUE;
                        }

                        PLIToUpdate.put(APLIU.Id,APLIU);
                        System.debug('---PLIToUpdate---'+PLIToUpdate);
                    }
                }
            }
        Update PLIToUpdate.values();
        APTS_ProposalLineItemTriggerHandler.IsUpdate = TRUE; 
    }

    //Purpose of this method is to update the end dates of 'Proposal Line Items' in the original proposal if they are moved to another Proposal and both of them have the overlapping Start and End dates. 
    Public Static Boolean IsStatusUpdate = TRUE;
    Public Static Void UpdateStatusOfOldPLI(List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c> OldPLI , List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c> NewPLI)
    {
        Set<ID> ProductIdSet = New Set<ID>();
        Set<ID> PriceListIdSet = New Set<ID>();
        Map<Id,Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c> PLIToUpdate = New Map<Id,Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c>();

        FOR(Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c PLI : NewPLI)
        {
            ProductIdSet.Add(PLI.Apttus_Proposal__Product__c);
            PriceListIdSet.Add(PLI.Apttus_QPConfig__PriceListId__c);
        } 

        List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c> FirstPLIList = [Select  Id, Publishing_Status__c, Apttus_Proposal__Product__c,
            Apttus_QPConfig__PriceListId__c, Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c, Apttus_QPConfig__StartDate__c, Apttus_QPConfig__EndDate__c FROM Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c 
            WHERE Apttus_Proposal__Product__c =: ProductIdSet AND Apttus_QPConfig__PriceListId__c =: PriceListIdSet AND ID NOT IN: NewPLI];

        List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c> ExecutedPLI = New List<Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c>();
        FOR(Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c PLIOld : OldPLI)
        {            
            FOR(Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c PLINew : NewPLI)
            {
                IF((PLIOld.Id == PLINew.Id) && (PLIOld.Publishing_Status__c != 'Published') && (PLINew.Publishing_Status__c == 'Published'))
                {
                    ExecutedPLI.Add(PLINew);
                }
            }
        }

        IF(ExecutedPLI.Size() != NULL)
        {
            FOR(Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c PLINew : ExecutedPLI)
            {
                FOR(Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c PLI1 : FirstPLIList)
                {
                    IF((PLINew.Apttus_Proposal__Product__c == PLI1.Apttus_Proposal__Product__c) && (PLINew.Apttus_QPConfig__PriceListId__c == PLI1.Apttus_QPConfig__PriceListId__c) && (PLINew.Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c != PLI1.Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c) && (PLI1.Apttus_QPConfig__EndDate__c > PLINew.Apttus_QPConfig__StartDate__c))
                    {
                        Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c APLIU = New Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c();

                        APLIU.Id = PLI1.Id;
                        APLIU.Apttus_QPConfig__EndDate__c = PLINew.Apttus_QPConfig__StartDate__c.adddays(-1);
                        PLIToUpdate.put(APLIU.Id,APLIU);
                    }
                    System.debug('---PLIToUpdate---'+PLIToUpdate);
                }
            }
        }
        Update PLIToUpdate.Values();
        APTS_ProposalLineItemTriggerHandler.IsStatusUpdate = TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: From a cursory look the problem may be as described in [Fixing a common cause of System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded](https://force201.wordpress.com/2014/11/09/fixing-a-common-cause-of-system-limitexception-apex-cpu-time-limit-exceeded/). The fix is generally to replace the inside loop with a map lookup.

Comment: Also, if you have process builder executing before this code it is likely the PB process fault and this code just gets  to report it.

Comment: @Eric : There are 2 PB running for Proposal object but don't know if they are contributing o this limit. There is a lot many code which is running for these 2 objects . The part I have posted is just 1/10th part or even lesser of the actual processes running behind. But as of now I am receiving CPU limit in these 2 methods only.

Comment: @KeithC: In my code I am not running the loops from parent-to-child or child-to-parent. It is always on (1st set of child records from 1st parent) and (2nd set of child records from 2nd parent). So I am unable to understand how to make use of maps here.

Comment: @Ruchi - Those may or may not be the cause. Sifting through the debug logs will help you see where the time is being spent. with CPU time the lines it is thrown on can be the cause or just the reporter where previous code took a long time. There are places for optimization for example the way you are setting object values is 10x slower than doing it like `Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c APLIU = New Apttus_Proposal__Proposal_Line_Item__c(Field=value,field=value);` Every little bit helps when you are processing in loops and running into this issue

Comment: Since this only happens with 200 or more records, in addition to looking at debug logs to see what kind of workflow occurs between updates, I suggest you use Dev Console Profile Tools to see where time is being consumed over course of each transaction. That may provide the insight into the source of your issue.